# Create a factory/service for an object that changes dynamically, and that could be passed on to a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object that updates via socket.io.

```js
var my_dynobj;
socket.on('update dynobj', function(dynobj){
    my_dynobj = dynobj;
});
```

I want to  have it in my angular app as a factory or a service that could be injected as a dependency.

In there I will want to attach `my_object` to a `$scope` so that it can be plugged into HTML `{{my_object}}` and will update whenever it is itself updated in its own factory definition via socket. `socket.on('update object', …`
But I can't figure out a way to make that happen.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .factory('dynobj_factory', [
    function(){
        var my_dynobj;
        socket.on('update dynobj', function(dynobj){
            my_dynobj = dynobj;
        });

        return {what?}

    }])
    .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'dynobj_factory',
    function($scope, dynobj) {

        $scope.my_dynobj = dynobj.what?

    }])
```

```html
<div>{{my_dynobj}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

```
return {/* what ? */}
```

You'll need to return something like;

```
return {dynamicObj: my_dynobj}
```

And that will do the trick. Any changes to `my_dynobj` will reflect through all directives, controllers, factories it is injected into.